# Performing calculations on Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a Google Form for an event registration. The admission charges to the event vary for the adults and children. An user can specify the number of adults and children registering for the event.
Is it possible to calculate the total charge the user would need to pay for the registration.
For example, the adult registration is $10 and child registration is $8. Assuming the user registers for 3 adults and 2 children, I want to display to the user that he/she would need to pay $46 ($10 x 3 + $8 x 2) for registration. Is this feasible on Google Forms. Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks
Rohit

Comment: Yes, this can be done with a script. Are you familiar with scripts?

Comment: You can't run client-side code, e.g. to create a question or label or item that says how much is due based on the current answers. You can, however, use a submit trigger to parse the submission and email the total due, etc. But note that this is no longer in the displayed form, and can't be in the response thank-you either - unless you want to display to the *next* user the previous user's total.

Comment: @xTwisteDx - Yes i understand code and scripts, but never worked on java script (if that is what that you mean to ask). I tried to search, but could not find anything to cater to my need. If you can throw some more light it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Create a sample form and link it here. I'll see if I can figure out a script for you.

Comment: I created a simple form. Here is the link
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeY3kzXfuH20uN-mylFC-3VQTOuS7dJqftodqJb3Etx7ySoZA/viewform?usp=sf_link
Let me know if you face problems accessing it.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal it doesn't work